# How to get bundle from an intent if multiple intents are passed to the service

Tags: java, android

I am passing intent to a service from two different locations in my application. One intent has a bundle from which I want to extract data.But I get NPE when I try run getIntent().getExtras() method.

EDIT:
In one class:

```
                        basket.putString("KEY1", id[i]);
                        basket.putString("KEY2", message[i]);
                        basket.putString("KEY3", timeFormat[i]);
                        passNotiData = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                CheckService.class);
                        passNotiData.putExtras(basket);
                        startService(passNotiData);
```

In another class,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
     context.startService(myIntent);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, PERIOD, pi);
```

And in service class,

```
Bundle gotBasket = intent.getExtras();
        oldId = gotBasket.getString("KEY1");
        oldTime = gotBasket.getString("KEY3");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//start service from activity or any place
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("TEST", "test got it.");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startService(intent);


//In service class declare override method of service
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            String str = intent.getExtras().getString("TEST");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: I am passing intent from two classes. Out of those two intents only one intent has bundle. How do I filter that intent?

Comment: You need to only check null operation for that. llike intent.getExtras() != null

Comment: Yes that will stop the error but how will I get those strings into my service?

Comment: If there is a bundle then you can got from above. If you want to pass your string to your service then you need to add bundle to intent and call startService(intent) method again.

Comment: I am calling `startService(intent)` method from both the classes. It recognizes only the intent which does not have Bundle.

Comment: You said that one intent has bundle and other has not. so the null pointer condition must be check before you want to parse that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73718/discussion-between-anand-makwana-and-hxt1022).

Comment: yes you are right but what if service is only getting the intent which does not have bundle? I will not be able to get the strings which I am passing though another intent.